# Enabling a Secrets Engine in Hashicorp Vault upon installation via Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I installed a Hasicorp Vault server via Helm with my custom values.yaml file (used this as a reference: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/helm/configuration)

I know I can enable different secrets engines after I initialize and unseal Vault (via the UI, CLI or API).

However, I am wondering whether it is possible to enable secrets engines via the values.yaml before initializing and unsealing Vault - i.e., when I open the UI after initializing and unsealing Vault I would like to see these engines already enabled and on the list of secrets engines (without enabling them manually).

I searched online for a way to do this but my efforts were in vain. I would really appreciate any answer on this subject.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was after the same thing, i.e. configuring enabled secret engines via Helm or via Vault configuration (and actually a bit more as I also wanted the ability to configure access policies).

I searched through most of the documentation and I believe that at the time of writing, i.e. 2023-03-22, this is simply not possible. You can only do such configuration via the CLI.